# Cross-build partprobe for ARM / Linux: configure error concerning libuuid

Tags: c, linux, cross-platform

I want to cross-build **partprobe** (e.g. parted-3.1 from [[here]](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/download.shtml) ) for an ARMv7-controller but keep getting error messages concerning **libuuid** and **uuid_generate**.

Actually I only need **partprobe** which may not even rely on that **uuid_generate** function, but I don't see any options in the *configure* script to disable any features.

I've successfully cross-built software before using the BPS as well as using the ARM toolchain provided by my distribution (Mint 17).

Here's what I've tried so far:

**1) Using the manufacturer's BSP**

I have a board support package that provides libraries and headers as well as a toolchain:

```
/path/to/bsp/_rootfs/lib/libuuid.so.1
/path/to/bsp/_rootfs/lib/libuuid.so.1.3.0
/path/to/bsp/board-support/linux-3.2.0-psp04.06.00.11/include/linux/uuid.h
/path/to/bsp/linux-devkit/am3352/bin/
```

When I invoke

```
./configure \
  --libdir=/path/to/bsp/_rootfs/lib/ \
  --includedir=/path/to/bsp/board-support/linux-3.2.0-psp04.06.00.11/include/ \
  --bindir=/path/to/bsp/linux-devkit/am3352/bin/ \
  --with-sysroot=/path/to/bsp/_rootfs \
  --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

I get the following error

```
checking for uuid_generate in -luuid... no
configure: error: GNU Parted requires libuuid - a part of the util-linux-ng package (but
usually distributed separately in libuuid-devel, uuid-dev or similar)
This can probably be found on your distribution's CD or FTP site or at:
    http://userweb.kernel.org/~kzak/util-linux-ng/
Note: originally, libuuid was part of the e2fsprogs package.  Later, it
moved to util-linux-ng-2.16, and that package is now the preferred source.
```

The **uuid.h** and libraries are available, so I thought the *configure* script should not complain, but the error seems to be misleading. The header **uuid.h** is available but does not contain a **uuid_generate** function declaration, while the library contains such a function (checked with **nm -D**).

I'm not sure what to do with that...does the BSP contain incompatible version of the header and the library?
However the busybox binary contains **wget** which seems to use **uuid_generate**...at some point it must have worked.

Replacing the original **uuid.h** with a **uuid.h.in** from the **/path/to/bsp/docs/am3352/licenses/e2fsprogs/** (which contains **uuid_generate**) still results in the same error.

**2) Using the Linux distro's ARM-environment**

I also tried using the ARM-toolchain provided by my Linux distribution (packages **gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf**, **libuuid1:armhf**)

```
aptitude install uuid-dev:armhf
```

shows conflicts with the x86 package of **uuid-dev**, but there are already available:

```
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/linux/uuid.h
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/linux/uuid.h
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libuuid.so.1
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libuuid.so.1.3.0
```

BTW: None of those two header files includes a string **uuid_generate**, while the libraries do.

Invoking

```
./configure host=arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

runs without errors, but creates a Makefile that lacks any info on the cross-build environment.

BTW: Invoking **make** anyway exits with error; trying the same with the current source code from **git://git.savannah.gnu.org/parted.git** configures and builds successfully, but no magic involved: the result are libraries/binaries for x86 and not for ARM.

Right now I'm at my wits' end - so my question is:

**Can someone see the problem(s) I'm missing?**

Comment: Did you figure this one out in the end? I'm stuck at the same problem more or less. For now, I just disabled device-mapper functionality. It's weird.

Comment: Btw.: If I don't compile for android (just don't issue the --host-option) the configure-script runs fine. I don't know what the addition of the host architecture changes, that it suddenly starts looking the luuid.

Comment: No. I've stopped working on that, the effort didn't justify the gain so far. I may continue trying if the priority changes.

Comment: Well, I succeeded now in getting past this error. I had to download and compile libuuid myself with the host-option for arm. But now I am stuck with a missing "scsi.h" and have no clue how to solve this to make parted-3.2.

Comment: I also solved the scsi.h-problem. It happened because I was using arm-linux-androideabi. This is linked against bionic instead of glibc. Therefor the error. Changed my toolchain to arm-linux-gnueabi and it works fine now.